# Two lists combination

Tags: netlogo

I have two lists for each agent. They show 1) to whom they are attracted and 2) whom they attracted.
I would like to make a new set variable that shows only those agents that are equally attracted to each other. Equal attraction is: the number of the agent (self) is in the 'attracting' list of the other agent and the number of the other agent is in the 'attracting' list for the first agent (self). My code so far:

```
    if attracted != nobody [set attractinglists fput ([self] of attracted) attractinglists]

    if attracted != nobody [set attrlists fput ([self] of attracting) attrlists]

    set attractinglist [self] of other turtles with [member? myself attrlists]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edited to better answer the question as clarified in the comments below.*

Alright so now, turtles will have a running list of all turtles to which they have ever been attracted. Every tick, turtles become attracted to three other turtles. They add those turtles to their "attracted-to" list (if they are not already on that list). Next, the turtles check if any of their "attracted-to" turtles have ever been attracted to them- if so, they will add that turtle to the "reciprocal-attraction" list (if it's not there already). Is that more what you were after?

```
turtles-own [
  attracted-to
  reciprocal-attraction      ;;; the turtles to which this turtle is attracted
]


to setup 
  ca
  create-turtles 10 [
    set attracted-to []
    set reciprocal-attraction []
  ]
end


to go  

  ask turtles [
    let temp-attraction sort n-of 3 other turtles
    show temp-attraction
    foreach temp-attraction [
      [x]->
      if ( member? x attracted-to = false ) [
        set attracted-to lput x attracted-to
      ]
    ]
  ]

  ask turtles [
    foreach attracted-to [ 
      [x]->
      if member? self [attracted-to] of x [
        if ( member? x reciprocal-attraction = false ) [
          set reciprocal-attraction lput x reciprocal-attraction
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]

end
```

Comment: It does not work. Keep in mind that attracted and attraction are lists that are updated during the ticks. They can be attracted in tick 10 to agent 2 but attract that agent 2 in tick 2. The code does not take that into account. Please help.

Comment: WITH expected input to be an agentset but got the list [] instead.

Comment: It does work; I ran the code above with turtles that update their attractions at the start of every tick. I have edited my answer to include the sole setup procedure needed so my answer now includes all the lines needed to make this execute properly. 
Your `with` error stems from using `with` with a list, such as "equal-attraction-list" created above, rather than an agentset. Note that in the code above, both `with` primitives are querying the agentset "attracted-to".

Comment: Thank you for you help. But yes, this code works but it does not satisfy my model. My agents build a list of all to whom they were attracted. I dont want them to completely override the attraction set. So if agent 1 has attracted [0, 2] in tick 1 and 2 and then agent 2 attracts agent 1 in tick 4. Then in tick 4 I need to have a variable that shows that agent 1 and 2 are in a set.

Comment: Ah I think I understand more clearly what you're after- I will update my answer again to see if I am right.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it a lot :-)